# Why will this page not work correctly when loaded dynamically in a div tag?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

This is an adaption of a much longer question, because I pinpointed the question to be more direct without so much information. I'm using [This](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm) to dynamically load pages in my div tag, but certain things stop working when loaded. Specifically some jquery stuff. The registration does not check the username ect when loaded in this div, and I can't figure out why. If code is needed to be posted I can do so, but I think it may simply lie in the way the pages are loaded, just not sure which or why. [Here](http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/index.php) is the link to my test page to see what I'm talking about. Hover over login then click "register". it will load the form but it doesn't check the username with the jquery and such I have. [Here](http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/register.php) is the single registration page that works just fine by itself, and this shows what I'm trying to do as well. [Fiddle with javascript/jquery and html](http://jsfiddle.net/3pTHv/1/). I left some PHP in just in case it's doing something funky, and left out the css because its for the message box, and that doesn't effect this, and will still show up for tests without it.

This is the PHP that process the registration:

```
<?php
//have to use &_POST instead of vars for regular vars because of bug
//hash the password
$hash = hash('sha256', $_POST['pass1']);

//creates a 3 character sequence, hash pass again
function createSalt(){    
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));    
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

//check registration code
require('config/config.php');
//match the id with the registration code to update the correct row
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE regcode=
'". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regcode']) ."'") or die('Unable to query!');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['id'] != "") {
    $updateid = $row['id'];
} else {
    die("No matching registration code!");
}

//check if id is blank, means registration is blank
if (isset($updateid)) {
//update into database
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET username='". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) ."', 
        password='". $hash ."', salt='". $salt ."', 
        email='". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) ."', 
        firstname='". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']) ."', 
        lastname='". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']) ."', 
        regcode='', joined=NOW(), lastlogin=NOW(), active='yes' 
        WHERE id='". $updateid ."'") or die(mysql_error());

//echo $query.",".$_POST['username'].",".$hash.",".$_POST['email'].",".$_POST['firstname'].",
//    ".$_POST['lastname'].",".$_POST['regcode'].",". $updateid ."";
//mysql_close();
echo 'yes';
} else {
echo 'noregcode'; 
}
?>
```

P.S. Please ignore outdated PHP. While it is bad, I just haven't fixed it yet and know I will have to soon.

Comment: This might seem harsh, but I'd avoid dynamicdrive.com like the **plague**.

Comment: I really didn't wanna use it, but didn't see anything else that I didn't really have to write anything and was more of a plug in. Was trying to save time but its starting to just take up more :)

Comment: +1 to the first comment. Copying things and asking other people why they don't work is not a good way of doing stuff. Programming requires a bit of understanding.

Comment: I have understanding, but have not used anything out of iFrames and am trying to stay away from them. I know what you mean, but at the same time that's a bit rude.... I obviously have quite a few other bits of programming done on my own, and didn't just copy and paste a site then ask you to fix it. This is something I don't understand and was hopeing to get insight on, not just destructive comments...

Comment: I took a look at the standalone registration page. It doesn't need to be a standalone page at all since there's nothing in `<head>`. If I were doing this, I'd put the `<form>` in the main page, then hide it  with jQuery `hide()` on `$(document).ready()`, then `show()` it when the `register` link is clicked. And I have to agree with the advice to stay away from dynamicdrive; not because copy/paste is bad, but because dynamicdrive code is hopelessly out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that that code you're using simply does nothing to make it work.  The code stuffs the response into a DOM element but doesn't try to run the scripts. A simple update to the `innerHTML` property of an element doesn't cause embedded scripts to be run.

You could modify that script if you want, but since you tagged this question with jQuery I would urge you in the strongest possible terms to dump that script and do this with jQuery, which (if you do it right) will do the work necessary to cause embedded scripts to be run.

Comment: Supposedly in the link for registration you put loadobjs in as well for css and js to be applied directly, but it's not working. Is there a short term fix to this or another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: That "loadobjs" function is for loading complete scripts.  It's not really clear what you want, but generally the quality of code from that site is abysmal.  It's not even **indented**.

Comment: I'm just trying to load pages dynamically in a div on the index page through the navigation links. I looked into .load() and other things, but wasen't too sure if that was what it was actually for.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what `.load()` is for.

Comment: jQuery load() function does exactly that -- take an external page, or even part of a page, and insert it in a container, like a div. If I wasn't on a phone, I'd create an example for you. External page does need to be in the same domain.

Comment: And will it load all elements associated with the page I'm loading? e.g. js and css files included on home.php, which is loaded inside index.php in a div?

Comment: Well one of the problems you're going to run into is that you're trying to load a *complete* page and then stuff it into an element in an *existing* page. That doesn't really make sense; an HTML element like a `<div>` can't have a whole 'nuther HTML page inside of it. Ideally, your server should just return an HTML fragment.

Comment: OP should read jQuery online document at http://api.jquery.com/load/ ... jQuery online docs are great, I always consult them when in doubt. If you attempt to .load() entire document, it evidently strips tags like <html><head>, but will execute javascript in the external document. javascript is not executed if you load only part of the external page.

Comment: load() is working besides one minor thing left. The form checks work, except for the first field (username). Also, my menu drop down gets stuck down on the registration page now too. I know this means something is probably colliding, I just don't see it. I read something somewhere about this but can't find it now. [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pTHv/2/). The navigation jquery is at the bottom of the javascript part. I kept the rest in there, just in case something else is doing it. You can also go on my test site in OP, click on projects and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I don't know if my server is being funny or what, but the first field of username checks correctly now. My navigation menu is still getting stuck though if anyone has any ideas....